# extract VBA userform from corrupted word docm

Tags: microsoft-word, vba, data-recovery

I have a userform in word built over 10+ years. Today Word chose to crash the normal.docm file and the VBA project became unreadable.

I have used python scripts to extract the code, but I don't have the form.

Is there a tool available to extract the userform from vbaProject.bin ? Or do I have to go the manual way and recreate everything from ground up ?

Comment: The `vbaProject.bin` file has the Form Designer data inside. It can just be unzipped, but you probably need the whole .bin file for Word to import it as a form. Depending on how it's corrupted, you may be able to clear certain parts out and re-zip the whole thing?

Comment: If you're *really* desperate, here are technical documents describing the structure of the [vbaProject.bin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-ovba/575462ba-bf67-4190-9fac-c275523c75fc) file contents, and the [Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-oforms/9c79701a-8c3e-4429-a139-b60ac3a1d50a) data itself, but it goes over my head

Comment: For future reference: The normal template is a; very poor location to store your important vba. Consider, in the future, using a separate Global template. Also backup your work, regularly. Here are two linksw on those topics. https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/MacrosVBA/OrganizeMacros.htm

Comment: @CharlesKenyon thank you for your suggestion and link. Did much reading up on how to do things, and will redo the project the "right way" using global templates.